# Create thickness on Hair on a material

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, geometry, hair

I have been struggling with making GeoNodes that will distrubute hair on a mesh/material/colour. This worked however the hair stay very thin, I am trying to find a way within GeoNodes how to alter this and need your guys help, as I am so stuck.
This is how my current GeoNodes set-up looks like.
The Upper part was just try-out to create thickness, but doesnt work sadly.
[image: GeoNodes set-up Hair distribution]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. [Blender 3.5 (scroll down)](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-5/) comes with pre-made GN groups and hair assets that use them.  You can stack them on the modifier stack. Try the *Set Hair Curve Profile* node to set the thickness. To see it in the viewport and Eevee you need to set the Eevee render setting Curves > Shape to Strip.

Comment: Your *Set Curve Radius* node has an error, it's the little white "[i]" in the top right corner. It's probably because the input is not of type "Curves" but mesh geometry or empty. Try to connect the *Curves* output of the *Generate Hair Curves* node to its input slot ("Curve"). You still need the Eevee render settings as described above to see the effect in the viewport if you are not in Cycles render mode.